# Sound Not Working Windows 10 v1809

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card

I recently installed Windows 10 Pro 1809 and I've got a weird sound problem, let me explain what's happening.

If I try to adjust the sound  here:

[image: volume adjust]

I can hear the "ting" sound that you hear when you adjust the volume. This is the only instance where I can hear it properly. Anything else -> Video Player, Google Chrome, does not play sound.

If open the volume mixer, I can see the green, but I can't hear any sound. If I adjust the "System sounds" I can see the green, but again cannot hear anything.

[image: volume mixer]

Looking online, I saw that updating audio drivers might work, but everything's up-to-date.
[image: drivers]

I also made sure my default speaker was set to the right one:

[image: devices]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please try going to "Audio Settings" -> "Change the device or app volume" -> "App Volume and Device Preferences". Open the app's in question and ensure that "Default" or the proffered audio device is selected. (App will not appear in list unless it is running)

Comment: [Make sure you actually have drivers that are compatible with 1809](https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/5993-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version.html).  Please provide the necessary information to identify the drivers you do have installed

Comment: @CraftyB Fixed it thanks. Just went to Sound Settings -> Troubleshoot -> Device -> Play Sound -> I didn't hear anything -> Play Sound Again -> I didn't hear anything -> Reinstall drivers and restart windows (sorry I didn't think of this :D, but thanks)

Comment: Restarting seems to fix it only temporarily here.

Comment: Do you have the branded Realtek software installed?  I truely believe this to be a driver incompatibility issue between Realtek and 1809

Answer (score 0):

that ring is a system sound placed in windows folder and used by OS, other sounds are need sound card driver to work correctly and be accessible by applications.

you need to reinstall your sound card driver, follow these steps

1- right-lick on Thispc and click on Manage

2- from the pane on the left click device manager

3- fined the audio input and out put

4- right-click on the child with speaker word and choose update driver and do it

if not fixed, do the same for audio and game... the child named display audio driver 
uninstall and then install it again

you can also install your sound driver from Cd or anything you have

restart your pc and check if it works fine

hope this helps